# Caculate WindowAvg with Date filter

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to calculate a 20 Day moving Avg using the WindowAvg function.  However I only want to show the latest days data.  Using a date filter to show most recent date only affects the 20 Day moving avg calculation.

WINDOW_AVG(COUNTD([SLIP_NUMBER]),LAST()-19,0)

Adding a date filter to only display current days 20 DayMovingAvg only gives me Count for the current day.

Comment: It would be easier to answer precisely if you posted some sample data and desired output.

Comment: One feature to consider is that you can hide data instead of filtering it. That is useful in cases when you want data available to impact calculations but don't want to display it. You can either select a header or marks to hide, or you can define a calculated field using a table calculation to put on the filter shelf.